# Firefox 4.0.1 on Windows 7 behaves differently after reinstalling it. Why?

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I cleaned my Windows 7 machine by repartitioning it and such. After I installed Firefox 4.0.1 back, I noticed some significant change in its behavior.

1. The downloads dialog didn't list out the files. I googled and found the solution to this. The settings were in some obscure place and I wonder how I got it the last time around!
2. The downloads dialog no longer shows the size of the file, percentage downloaded etc under the progress bar.
3. The icon on the taskbar is no longer getting filled with a greenish tinge to indicate the progress of the downloads.

For the last two, I googled but didn't get anything.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you have to use that (old) version of Firefox?

Comment: Gosh! There have been a release a month. I must have been living under a rock. Geez. But till I get a latest version I still need to know how to solve these issues.

Comment: I'm just asking since it will be very hard for other people to find a solution that works for that specific version, as it is rather uncommon today (or so I assume).

Comment: I downloaded and installed 10.0.2 and everything is back to normal. I don't want beta. Thanks for this completely unexpected solution!

Comment: Great :) If you don't mind, answer your own question and come back to mark it as the correct solution. That would be appreciated.